# Register view from laravel doesn't show and recognize the variable from my controller Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

***I have a select in my view that shows the information i want to select, the view is the register from laravel,but i added other forms, the form with method `POST` that has the select doesn't recognize the variable from the controller, i did the same in my own views and works i dont know why doesn't work in the register view from Laravel,tried but didnt work***

- Below i will let the code of my route,my `index function()`, my `create function()` and my select
- I have this error `Undefined variable: empleado`, repeat only happen with the register from Laravel
- The thing i want is that the person see the options of the select and select one , then i save it in my database

***Route***

```php
Route::resource('/empleado', 'EmpleadoController');
```

*** `index function()`***

```php
public function index()
    {   
        return view('home.home2');
    }
```

*** `store function()` ***

```php
public function create()
    {   
        $empleado = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT 
                                        nombre_cargo,id_cargo
                                        FROM cargo"
                                        ));
        return view('auth.register')->with('empleado',$empleado);
    }
```

*** `<select>`***

```html
<form method="POST" action="/empleado">
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="country" class="col-md-5 col-form-label text-md-right tamano">Cargo</label>
                <div class="select-wrap col-md-7">
              <select name="fk_cargo" id="" class="form-control tamano">
                  @foreach ($empleado as $item)
                    <option value="{{$item->id_cargo}}">{{$item->nombre_cargo}}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query builder table and get method to get the results.

Try to use this code below.

```
public function create()
{   
   $empleado = DB::table('cargo')->select('nombre_cargo','id_cargo')->get();
   return view('auth.register', compact('empleado'));
}
```

Have a look to this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) from laravel

Comment: I used post method because i will save the value of the select

Answer (score 0):

This is your **create** function. I'd advocate adopting the Laravel's magic method when passing variables to the view as its always simple:

```
    public function create()
            {   
                $empleado = DB::table('cargo')->select('nombre_cargo','id_cargo')->get();
                return view('auth.register',[
    'empleado'=>$empleado
]);
            }
```